# How can I make the connection between these li in different angles?

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm trying to make an interactive homepage where these bubbles will be scattered around the page and It's also the menu where I can go to different pages just by click on each one of them, something like an IoT linked chain.
Now I'm stuck at figuring out how to change the angles because I don't want it to be on the same level.

```css
#large-dots {
$line-width: 1px;
$line-color: #008CBA;

$circle-size: 40px;
$circle-space: 20px;
$circle-color: #008CBA;

display: inline-block;
width: auto;
color: #333333;
font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Roboto,Arial,sans-serif;

ul.chains {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;

    &::before {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        border-color: $line-color;
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 0 0 $line-width 0;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: -1;
        top: $circle-size;
    }
}

li.chain {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
    background-color: $circle-color;
    margin-left: $circle-space;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: $circle-size;
    height: $circle-size;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: $circle-size;
    vertical-align: middle;

    &.enabled {
      width: $circle-size * 2;
      height: $circle-size * 2;
      line-height: $circle-size * 2;

      .price {
        /**
         * If I change the font size, the circle
         * alignment gets screwed up
         */

        font-size: 1.25em;
      }
    }

    &:first-child {
        margin-left: 0;
    }
}

.price {
    font-size: 1.25em;
}
.smallround:hover {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: blue;
  margin-left: $circle-space;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: $circle-size;
  height: $circle-size;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: $circle-size;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.biground:hover {
display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: #FFFF00;
  margin-left: $circle-space;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: $circle-size * 2;
  height: $circle-size * 2;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: $circle-size * 2;
  vertical-align: middle;
 }

 }
```

```html
<div id="large-dots" class="example-container">
  Example of Landing Page
  <ul class="chains">
    <li class="chain enabled">
      <div class="price biground">Home Page</div>
    </li>
    <li class="chain">
      <div class="price smallround"></div>
    </li>
    <li class="chain enabled">
      <div class="price biground">Contact</div>
    </li>
    <li class="chain">
      <div class="price smallround"></div>
    </li>
    <li class="chain">
      <div class="price smallround"></div>
    </li>
    <li class="chain enabled">
      <div class="price biground">About</div>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: So you want the <li> to be scattered around with different angles ?

Comment: Yes exactly, I don't know if that's a possibility with HTML, CSS only but I'm still trying to figure it out, I want to make it look attractive because of how it looks right now it feels really outdated and too simple

Comment: I run it on codepen btw.

Comment: save it as a pen and provide the pen link so can check there

Comment: https://codepen.io/rasbsal/pen/OJmyRYd

Comment: What do you want it to look like on different aspect ratio viewports? You may need some JS for angle calculations, depending on exactly your requirement.

Comment: I think this might do It https://github.com/musclesoft/jquery-connections
it seems like the best option for me and I think JS is the best solution for it